# UITextField editable only for some range

Tags: ios, uitextfield

In my application I need to prefix some text (say ABC) in UITextField
which is not editable.Any character entering in this textfield should be followed by that text which is editable.(if I enter 123 then the the text should be ABC123, 123 part is editable).How to do this

Answer (score 1):

you need to play with the `UITextField` delegates

Sample code

Every time set prefix for the UITextFiled, If it is empty

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
     if ([self.txtPhoneNo.text isEqualToString: @""]) {
                self.txtPhoneNo.text = @"ABC";
            }
    }
```

Editable for only after certain prefix range

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
    NSString * searchStr = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

 NSString *prefixString = @"ABC";
        NSRange prefixStringRange = [searchStr rangeOfString:prefixString];
        if (prefixStringRange.location == 0) {
            // prefix found at the beginning of result string

            NSCharacterSet *cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:NUMBERS_ONLY] invertedSet];
            NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
            return ([string isEqualToString:filtered]);
        }
        return NO;

}
```

Reset the TextField, if there is no text, except prefix

```
  -(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
     if ([self.txtPhoneNo.text isEqualToString:@"ABC"]) {
                self.txtPhoneNo.text =@"";
            } 
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Initially put `ABC` in your `UITextField` in viewDidLoad or xib or where ever you want.

```
yourTextField.text=@"ABC";
```

then You can use this.

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if ([textField.text isEqualToString:@"ABC"] && [string isEqualToString:@""]) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty simple

```
- (BOOL)                textField : (UITextField *)textField
    shouldChangeCharactersInRange : (NSRange)range
                replacementString : (NSString *)string
{

    if (range.location <= [@"ABC" length]) {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

### how it works:

```
USER EDITS TEXTFIELD (either paste/replace or direct editing)
|
|
V
SYSTEM WILL CALL shouldChangeCharacterInRange
                 |
                 |
                 V
                 if you return true from this, then editing takes place
                 else, changes will be discarded
```

The range object contains `location` (where the change in text begins) and `length` (from `location`, how many characters will change).

So,

- if `location <= 3`, ie., user is editing @"ABC", which we should prevent, return `NO`
- For all other cases, user is editing some where else in the textfield, return `YES`

you can replace `[@"ABC" length]` with pre-calculated length value if you want to optimize it further.

Answer (score 0):

Initially put ABC in your UITextField in viewDidLoad or xib or where ever you want.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:(id)self selector:@selector(textFieldChangeCharacters:) name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object:nil];


-(void)textFieldChangeCharacters:(id)sender{

     UITextField *textField = [(NSNotification *)sender object];
     NSLog(@"Textfield Text = %@",textField.text);
     if (textField.text.length < @"ABC".length) {
        textField.text = @"ABC";
     }


}
```